# SSIS Concurrent Connections

Tags: ssis

We have developed a simple web app which allows a user to upload an excel file. Our system picks the excel file and triggers an SSIS simple task to read an incoming excel file with 6 columns and push the data in the database.

Our concern is what will happen when mutiple users try to upload files simultaneously? Can SSIS serve multiple requests at the same time (which it should)?

What is the upper limit ie how many requests can it perform simultaneously?

What advice and suggestions you can give us in order for us have our server configured so that we can serve maximum requests?

Comment: Do the excel files need to be processed directly after they are uploaded? And which sql server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

same SSIS package can run more that once at the same time. The concerns you must have are the same concerns as if you were running 2 insert statments at the same time. SSIS is only the way you are using to insert the data. What happens when the data reaches the SQL Server engine is regardless of how it got there.

Just rememebr that SSIS uses bulk inserts